# Lettrine, accentuated characters and htlatex

Tags: errors, accents, tex4ht, lettrine, htlatex

I use accentuated letters with the `lettrine` package like:

```
\lettrine{É}{lisée} avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
```

With `luatex` (which is my normal rendering engine), it works fine. However, when I try to use TeX4HT to build HTML from it, I get:

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.805 \lettrine{É}{lisée}
                            avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
```

I have already added these two lines when building with `htlatex`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and I call `htlatex` with:

```
htlatex sagesse_lulu.tex 'xhtml,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

Comment: I can run simple document with lettrine without compilation errors, can you post complete example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple example runs without errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{tex4ht}{
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
}{
\usepackage{fontspec}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage[]{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{É}{lisée} avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie. avait vu le pouvoir de Dieu sur la vie d'Élie.
\end{document}
```

However, output looks bad, because there is no `tex4ht` configuration for `\lettrine`. Simple configuration can look like this: 
file `lettrine.4ht`

```
\NewConfigure{lettrine}{4}
\renewcommand\lettrine[2]{%
\leavevmode 
\a:lettrine#1\b:lettrine\c:lettrine#2\d:lettrine
}
\Configure{lettrine}{\ifvmode \ShowPar\fi \HCode{<span class="lettrine-init">}}{\Tg</span>}{\Tg<span class="lettrine-line">}{\Tg</span>}
\Css{.lettrine-init{
font-size:2em;
}}

\Css{.lettrine-line{
font-variant:small-caps;
}}
```

This file is called automatically when you usepackage `lettrine`.

We created configurable hooks with `\NewConfigure{lettrine}{4}`. This creates four hooks, named `\a:lettrine` ... `\d:lettrine`
Then we redefined `\lettrine` command to put these hooks. Rest of the file is default configuration for tags and css information for their styling. You can redefine them in custom `cfg` file

Comment: This is great! I've been looking for an explanation like this one, and was using some horrible `sed` hacks instead. Is there a reference for such usage of TeX4HT somewhere?

Comment: I'm wondering now if the problem I had was because I still had auxiliary files from a previous PDF build. Auxiliary files tend to cause conflicts between rendenders.

Comment: There is only little documentation -  in LaTeX web companion, there are some chapters that goes into depth, there are also good articles on CVR's blog - http://www.cvr.cc/tex/tex4ht/ but I think that I learned the trick with `\a:configname` from source codes of various `.4ht` files

Comment: it could be `aux` files, if one was writen in luatex using utf8 and then read by pdftex, it causes sometimes errors

Comment: I wonder if it would be interesting to get a standard `lettrine.4ht` added to TeX4HT.

Comment: I realized that first version caused problems with paragraphs, as we discussed that in another question today, so I edited configuration, but I cannot test it now, hope it works.

Comment: I didn't have problems with paragraphs with the original code, but I had to add support for options (at least phony support, but I do support the `ante` option).

Comment: The code provided by michal.h21 shall be added to TeX4ht in the next release.

Comment: @CVRadhakrishnan I think there is more elaborated version of lettrine.4ht provided by ℝaphink: https://github.com/cc-translators/sagesse/blob/master/lettrine.4ht

Comment: @michal.h21 OK. Will have a look at this and will make use of the code.